# What is a word for "people who converse"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

What is a word for "people who converse"?

I'm trying to write a pretty long essay for my English class, but I can't figure out what this word is.

Comment: What is the context the word will be used in? There are many words for people who _speak_, but are you looking for a more formal word?

Comment: Talkers, gabbers, folks chewing the fat.

Comment: Or (ducking the brick-bats!), women.

Comment: You should be more specific about what context and situation you'd like to use the word. otherwise it's difficult to answer.

Comment: What are the generous close votes for -- does a close vote mean you don't understand the question or don't know the answer?

Answer (score 2):

*[interlocutor](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interlocutor)* (ODO)

> *formal*
>   A person who takes part in a dialogue or conversation.
>   *All of these narratives unfold partly as dialogues with what seem to be sympathetic but ineffectual interlocutors, perhaps lawyers.*

See also,
[Interlocutor (linguistics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutor_%28linguistics%29) (Wikipedia)

> In linguistics, discourse analysis, and related fields an **interlocutor** is a person involved in a conversation or dialogue. Two or more people speaking to one another are each other's interlocutors.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutor_%28linguistics%29) The terms *conversation partner*,[3] *hearer*,[4] or *addressee*[5] are sometimes used interchangeably with *interlocutor*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for **[conversationalist](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/conversationalist)**? [Oxford]

> A person who is good at or fond of engaging in conversation
>
> *an entertaining conversationalist*

Please provide additional context.

`speaker` and `talker` may also serve the purpose.